# symfony - unique entity constraint with not mapped field

Tags: validation, symfony, constraints, lifecycle, unique-constraint

my goal is to validate an entity with a uniqueEntity constrainte on a field. This field is composed of 2 not mapped fields concatenated using a lifecycle callback PrePersist. The problem is that the validation does not occur and the system allows me to insert data into the database when it should not.

```
/**
* Recipe
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\RecipeRepository")
* @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
* @UniqueEntity(
*     ignoreNull = false,
*     fields={"amount"},
*     message="Not valid"
* )
*/
class Recipe
{...}
```

...

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function preSave()
{
    $this->amount = $this->getAmountInteger() . '.' . $this->getAmountDecimal();
}
```

Comment: What about `@ORM\Column(name="amount", type="string", length=255, unique=true)` above attribute `amount` _(keep your UniqueEntity constraint)_ ?

Comment: Isn't `unique=true` intended for schema tool only?

Comment: @Delphine, with the unique=true constraint setted on field, I can't validate correctly my form and handle the uniqueness of the row. In fact, the check comes with the flush and not with the form valid method.

Comment: Maybe a little "hack" in your __construct() method to set it to an empty string ?

Comment: @Delphine can you explain please?

Comment: Yes, just add, in your `Recipe` Entity, this method with this setting `public function __construct()  {  $this->amount = "" };`. Thanks to this, your `amount` field will never be null at creation.

Answer (score 0):

i have a entity with this definition and run fine, but your case is different because your set 'amount' in the preSave...

```
 *   @UniqueEntity(fields={"amount"}, message="Not valid")
 *   @ORM\Table(uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_amount", columns={"amount"})})
```

And in the other entity i used

```
@ORM\Column(type="string", length=127, nullable=false, unique=TRUE)
```

The different is in the first case i use compuest key and define key in the fields={field1,field2}.. in the second example i use simple unique key.